# How can I write to next line of a file in each run of a program?

Tags: python, c++, ofstream

I have a python script that runs my C++ program. And after each call I want to write something to the next line of my file. I can just write to first line of the file. What should I do in order to write the next line without affecting the previous lines? Thanks in advance.

**C++ Side: my.cpp** takes x, y, z as inputs.

```
char calc(int x,int y,int z)
{
    if(x+y+z<=10) return '0';
    return '1';
}

std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("file.txt");
myfile << calc(x,y,z) << std::endl;
myfile.close();
```

**Python Side:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system("make my")
    subprocess.check_output(['./my', x, y, z])
```

Comment: Open the file for appending (`ios::app`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to open for append:

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
```

Comment: Thanks, I also need an empty file if I run my python script again. (When I run the script it should start from the beginning.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It sounds like you are contradicting yourself.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. My python script runs my code several times. But when I run my python script again it should start writing from the beginning of file.txt

Comment: @ghhgnıı have you tried emptying the file in python?

Comment: @user2079303  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you might want to pass an additional option to `std::ofstream::open`:

```
myfile.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::app);
```

This will append anything that your write to that file. From python, you can delete the file like this

```
import os

os.remove("file.txt")
```

which will cause the compiled executable to append to a newly created file.